# JMeter high rates error facebook (all.js)

Tags: web-applications, facebook-javascript-sdk, jmeter

I'm testing my app with JMeter, the problem is that I have 59 % errors with /fr_FR/all.js.

[image: Report JMeter]

This file is Facebook API. Is there something to configure in JMeter or is it a normal error rates ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Can you give some details about your test ? Test plan overview ? you are downloading static resources (yes)? Parallel download ? How many threads ? You seem to be running in GUI mode , any distributed testing ?....

Comment: This test is just to see if there is a big problem. Details : 100 threads, ramp-up period : 50 sec and 3 loop.

The URL of the file is http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js.

Comment: Read this:http://www.dzone.com/links/see_how_to_make_jmeter_run_thousands_of_threads_w.html Your tests is not correct I think. I wanted details about the Test plan content.